# CakePHP find on a json encoded field

Tags: json, model, controller, cakephp-2.0

I am creating a store in CakePHP and have added a text field which stores a json array of all the categories the store falls into.

How do I do a cake find on all stores that fall into the "gardening" category?

json encoded field:

```
["gardening","books-and-toys"]
```

I am thinking some sort of in_array() find but not quite sure.

Many Thanks

Comment: Were you ever able to get an answer on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP method [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and return the JSON object as an associative array by setting the second option of that function to `true`. You can then call [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) for example to return the corresponding key.

```
<?php
  $categories = json_decode($json, true);
  $categoryKey = array_search('gardening', $categories);
  $categoryName = $categories[$categoryKey];
?>
```

You can then use `$categoryName` in a CakePHP `find()` call.